# how do i remove the similar word in strings?

Tags: c

I have program to remove the similar words from string but this program only removing at once word not a repeating words.

For example input:

```
sabunkerasmaskera kera
```

and should an output:

```
sabunmas
```

This my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove(char x[100], char y[100][100], char words[100]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; x[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (x[i] == ' ') {
            y[k][j] = '\0';
            k++;
            j = 0;
        } else {
            y[k][j] = x[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    y[k][j] = '\0';
 
    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
        if (strcmp(y[i], kata) == 0) {
            y[i][j] = '\0';
        }
    }
 
    j = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
        if (y[i][j] == '\0')
            continue;
        else
            printf("%s ", y[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main() {
    char x[100], y[100][100], kata[100];
    printf ("Enter word:\n");
    gets(x);
 
    printf("Enter word to remove:\n");
    gets(words);
    
    remove(x, y, words);
    
    return 0;
}
```

My program output its:

```
sabunkerasmaskerara
```

and that should not be the case. Maybe I need your opinion to fixed this program and also I need help to make it better.

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does that you did not expect?

Comment: First of all ***never*** use `gets` in your programs. It's [so dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that it even have been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: the program should an output sabunmas, but m program doesn't

Comment: Also, when you create a [mcve] to show us, please make sure it replicates or describes the problem you ask about *only*. If the shown code have other errors then it tend to distract from the actual problem. And if you claim you have a running program, then showing us code that won't even build is pretty bad. And why pass `y` as an argument, instead of defining it as a local variable inside the function?

Comment: sorry,I'll make a better question next time @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: As for your problem, all you really need are the [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr), [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) and [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) functions, together with some knowledge about arrays, pointers and pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Given the input `sabunkerasmaskerara`, are you sure the desired output isn't `sabunsmasra` ?

Comment: yes i try but not the desired output @MarkBenningfield

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not work because it uses `strcmp` to compare the string portions, which only works if the substring is at the end of the string, as this makes it null-terminated.

You should instead use `strstr` to locate the matches and use `memmove` to shift the string contents.

There are other issues in your code:

- do not use `gets()`
- `y` is unnecessary for this task.
- `words` is not defined

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *remove_all(char *str, const char *word) {
    size_t len = strlen(word);

    if (len != 0) {
        char *p = str;
        while ((p = strstr(p, word)) != NULL) {
            memmove(p, p + len, strlen(p + len) + 1);
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char str[100], word[100];

    printf ("Enter string:\n");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;
 
    printf("Enter word to remove:\n");
    if (!fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin))
        return 1;
    
    word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline if any

    remove_all(str, word);
    
    fputs(str, stdout);

    return 0;
}
```